# Flash/FLV Media Player with .NET API

Tags: asp.net, flv, flash

I am looking for a media player which I can control via an ASP.NET/Javascript API and also set playlists dynamically (ie from a datasource).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll find one that is specifically .net orientated. However, quite a lot will use XML for playlists. So, your best bet would be to generate an XML file 'on-the-fly' from your Datasource and pass it the FLV Player via an .ashx handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to integrate with JW FLV Player:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/

It has the features you require:

- It supports [xml playlists](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats#XMLPlaylists)
- It can be [controlled with javascript](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashApi)

It's not designed to integrate specifically with .NET, but I doubt there are any flv flash players that are.

I've used it with java and php.

Answer (score 0):

There is one commercial player that implemented as web control and can be simple dragged from toolbox - http://aspnetflashvideo.com/. To set FLV file to playback you simple set MovieURL property to correct location and thats all...

Comment: I tried that one. It had some obvious flaws and when I asked a question about certain lacking functionality it was deleted from the product forums.